# Access array of 32-bit words as other sizes

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, casting

I'm struggling to get my mind around using pointers and arrays. I need some simple assistance with methods and conventions. I did see some similar posts, but I'm afraid I'm still at the point where I need very literal examples.

I have an array of 32-bit numbers that represent word-aligned data in a UDP packet. I need to access this data as 16-bit numbers for calculating the header checksum, and as 8-bit numbers when stuffing data. I have a statically defined buffer that I pass to my routine as

```
alt_u16 calc_udp_header_chksum (alt_u32 hdr[])
{
....

}
```

- Could someone help me with examples of how to access this as alt_u16,
  alt_u8 using pointers and or arrays?
- Would this be something that
  would be clearer to write by passing a pointer into the routine? If
  so, an example would be helpful.

Comment: `I did see some similar posts` on SO? Looks like a new account with only one post. If you did other posts on SO under a different user name maybe link to them and what the continued confusion is.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply cast `hdr` to be a `alt_u16*`. Like this:

```
alt_u16* hrd_word_aligned = (alt_u16*)hdr;
```

And now you can use `hrd_word_aligned[0]` for the first 16 bit value, `hrd_word_aligned[1]` for the second, and so on.

Analagous code can be used for `alt_u8*`.

It doesn't matter whether your function receives `alt_u32 hdr[]` or `alt_u32 *hdr`.

Comment: Thanks. btw: the endian issue did come up; my processor is little-endian and ethernet is big-endian. Also, most references just say that the UDP header checksum covers the IP header without explicitly saying what bytes are covered. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4_header_checksum) shows what bytes are used and gives a concrete example.

Comment: use `ntohs` to convert from network byte order to host byte order. Try and get in to the habit if thinking in terms of host and network byte order rather than little and big endian.

Answer (score 0):

Down casting is not a problem.

You only need to cast the pointer to the new type. For example :

```
alt_u16* hrd16 = (alt_u16*)hdr;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just cast from `(alt_u32*)` to `(alt_u16*)`.

But endianness (byte order) may affect the result. I don't know details about what byte order you have.

**THE CODE**

```
alt_u16 calc_udp_header_chksum (alt_u32 hdr[])
{
   int i;
   alt_u16 ans = 0;
   for(i=0; i<correct_size; ++i) {
      ans+=((alt_u16*)hdr)[i];
   }
   return ans;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I got it working. btw: You were right about endian being an issue. Ethernet is big-endian but my processor is little-endian. Most web references say that the chksum covers the ip header, but do not describe exactly what part of the header is covered. [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4_header_checksum) shows exactly the segment of the header that is covered by the checksum.